# How to set session cookie on frontend when frontend and backend are on different domains

Tags: node.js, cookies, passport.js, session-cookies, setcookie

I am working on a fullstack project that has a React + Next.js frontend and a REST API built with Express + Node.js + MongoDB for the backend. The authentication system was to be implemented using passportjs with the passport-google-oauth20 strategy. I've chosen to use a session cookie rather than a JWT token for user authentication. As I've understood, one step in this process is setting a cookie on the frontend that stores the session data. Having followed some tutorials, I built a frontend + backend that works on my localhost. The cookie however, was not getting set in the deployment, where my frontend is hosted on vercel (https://vercel.com) and my backend on render (https://render.com).

Believing the issue to be with passport.js, I spent hours parsing my backend code and chasing different solutions. Finally, I chanced upon the Network tab (which I should have checked first) and found this:

[set-cookie header in network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INg5N.jpg)

As you can see, I am being warned that "This attempt to set a cookie via a Set-Cookie
header was blocked because its Domain
attribute was invalid with regards to the current
host url."

After some research, I found some StackOverflow answers mentioning the use of "subdomains". From what I've understood, having your backend and frontend on different subdomains of the same domain is the only way to fix this problem. Am I right with this supposition? Is there no way for me to store cookies on my frontend hosted at say: https://project_name.vercel.app, sent from my backend hosted at https://project_name.onrender.com?

Here is the code for my index.ts:

```
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cors from "cors";
import passport from "passport";
import { errorHandler } from "./middleware/error.middleware";
import session from "express-session";
import MongoStore from "connect-mongo";

import { initDB } from "./config/initDB";
import { initPassport } from "./config/initPassport";
import authRouter from "./routers/auth.router";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import opportunityRouter from "./routers/opportunity.router";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";

const app = express();
dotenv.config();

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: process.env.FRONTEND_BASE_URL,
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.set("trust proxy", 1);

// Not required as cors package takes care of it
// app.use((req, res, next) => {
//   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
//   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
//   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
//   next();
// });

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

initDB();

const mongoStore = MongoStore.create({
  client: mongoose.connection.getClient(),
  collectionName: "sessions",
  autoRemove: "interval",
  autoRemoveInterval: 1, // In minutes
});

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: mongoStore,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, // Session expiration time in milliseconds
      sameSite: "none",
      secure: true,
      httpOnly: true,
      domain: process.env.DOMAIN, //Set to .vercel.app (frontend)
    },
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

initPassport();

app.use("/auth", authRouter);
app.use("/opportunity", opportunityRouter);

app.use(errorHandler);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Backend server is running on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

My question is similar to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/425184/how-do-you-set-cookies-on-frontend-from-the-backend, but I would like to achieve the same result without having to configure sub-domains.

Comment: #0 If the backend is a pure nodejs , why are you using Next.js as frontend instead pure react? #1 "different subdomains of the same domain is the only way to fix this problem" >>> No #2 Is the error at login or when api is consumed? #3 Next has these "rare things". #4 React with google login and rest api is so easy with JWT.

Comment: @JRichardsz
#0 I need the SEO benefits of using Next.js.
#1 Good to know, but how do I go about doing this?
#2 The issue occurs during login, the cookie is not set. The backend doesn't throw any error.
#3 True, I did see some issues online. But I assumed that wasn't the case here.
#4 Agreed, but I wanted to try out the method of session cookies for this project. I have used JWT for previous projects and it is definitely way more straightforward.

Comment: Well, I've fixed the issue by configuring a subdomain (www.backend.project_name.com) for my backend, with the frontend hosted on www.project_name.com. Seems like this can only be done if you own a domain. My question of whether this can be done without using subdomains still stands though.